# AWS EC2 CentOS 7 Port 80 blocked despite correct rules

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, firewall, port

I have a web server instance running apache on aws, It stopped working suddenly. I've checked port in the security group and both port 80 and 443 are open both for ip4 and ip6. I have no firewall running on the service, both firewall and iptables are disabled. When I run telnet `telnet 18.156.179.95 80` I get a connection time out. Apache is running and listening to the port, checked this by running `systemctl status httpd`which returned

`Active: active (running) since Tue 2022-09-06 04:28:29 UTC; 31min ago`

and ran
`netstat -tnlp | grep :80` which returned

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1329/httpd
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      1329/httpd
```

This is how my security group looks like
[image: List of ports inbound rules]

I am really at a lose here and as always all help is much appreciated.

P.S. Worth mentioning other services running on other ports are working fine

Comment: What commands ping 18.156.179.95 and ip addr says? "I stopped working suddenly" - what it means exactly? What config files of your webserver?

Comment: @gapsf I meant the webserver stopped working suddenly, when i ping the ip it gets a timeout, worth mentioning other services running on other ports are working fine

Comment: @gapsf the instance is running, but I cant reach apache listening to port 80, there isn't even a connection made as I can see in the logs, so I assume for some reason the port is blocked

Comment: Check apache cinfiguration and restart it. Use tcpdump to check traffic try 443 port if it configured in apache

Comment: its the default httpd config and as before no traffic reaches the httpd service, I assume aws is blocking the traffic somehow even though the security rules are correct

Comment: check with tcodump, restart apache, reload instance, talk to aws

Comment: Pardon for my left-field question; but do you have enough disk space?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for trying to help. As It happens to be this problem was apparently due to aws suspending thoose ports because of malware. For future reference make sure to check.
[The Health Status Dashboard](https://health.aws.amazon.com/health/home#/account/dashboard/open-issues) and its history. Because at first glance it might say healthy as it did for me but after further investigation it showed in the event log that I had been notified that these action would be taken if the problem wasn't resolved.